# How can I cache a wagtail page?

Tags: caching, wagtail

how can I cache a Page in Wagtail? The default url way or cache_page decorator are not working:
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf][1]

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

Comment: if still interested, maybe you can find this useful https://chamsoft.co.uk/blog/-view-cache-django-wagtail-cms/

Answer (score 0):

Since Wagtail often automates the view for you, the easiest method I've found is to cache at the template layer:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

Wagtail also provides support for a front-end cache like Varnish, but that's another service to maintain.

Comment: However, see this issue "Template fragment caching potentially harmful" https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5074